# Horizontal RecyclerView inside Vertical RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make something like this. [image]

So the idea is that i have vertical recyclerview with channels and on second position of channel I should have a horizontal recyclerview with relives.

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do that, I tried messing with viewholders and guess I should make only one recyclerview in my channel_details layout, and another one as an item in item_channel_details, but I cant get it to work.

Here is my code.

ChannelDetailsActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_channel_details);

    ImageView coverPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_cover_details);
    final HexagonImageView avatarPhoto = (HexagonImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_hex);
    TextView toolbarText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_toolbar_title);

    final Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    final MNetworkChannel parcelChannel =
            b.getParcelable(Const.IntentData.H_CHANNEL_LIST);

    final MVideosForChannel parcelVideosForChannel = b.getParcelable(Const.IntentData.D_VIDEOS_LIST);




    setChannelsView();
    setVideosView();


}

private void setChannelsView() {

    rvRelive = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_relive_details);
    rvRelive.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    adapterRelives = new ReliveAdapter();
    rvRelive.setAdapter(adapterRelives);

    if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Const.IntentData.D_RELIVE_LIST) != null) {
        adapterRelives.setData(((ReliveMainPojo) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Const.IntentData.D_RELIVE_LIST)).relives);
    }
}

private void setVideosView() {

    rvVideos = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_videos);
    rvVideos.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    adapterVideos = new ChannelVideosAdapter();
    rvVideos.setAdapter(adapterVideos);

    if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Const.IntentData.D_VIDEOS_LIST) != null) {
        adapterVideos.setData(((MVideosForChannel) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Const.IntentData.D_VIDEOS_LIST)).experience);
    }
}
```

ChannelDetails adapter:

```
public final class ChannelVideosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChannelVideosAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<MVideo> data = new ArrayList<>();

public ChannelVideosAdapter() {
}

public void setData(List<MVideo> newData) {

    if (newData != null && !newData.isEmpty()) {

        data = newData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void clearData() {

    data.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public final ChannelVideosAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_video_recycle_tile, parent, false));
}

@Override
public final void onBindViewHolder(final ChannelVideosAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final MVideo video = data.get(position);

    final String videoBackgroundImageUrl = video.asset.frame;
    final String videoName = video.name;

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(videoBackgroundImageUrl, holder.coverPhoto, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            holder.videoLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            holder.videoLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            holder.videoLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            holder.videoLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    holder.videoName.setText(videoName);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            VideoPlayerActivity.StartNewVideoPlayerActivity((ChannelDetailsActivity) holder.itemView.getContext(), video, true);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public final int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

final class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final ImageView coverPhoto;
    private final TextView videoName;
    private final ProgressBar videoLoading;

    ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        coverPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail_background_video);
        videoName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_video_name);
        videoLoading = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pb_video_loading);
    }
}
}
```

Relive Adapter:

```
public final class ReliveAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReliveAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Relive> data = new ArrayList<>();

public ReliveAdapter() {
}

public void setData(List<Relive> newData) {

    if (newData != null && !newData.isEmpty()) {

        data = newData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void clearData() {

    data.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public final ReliveAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_relive_recycle_tile, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ReliveAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final Relive relive = data.get(position);

    final String reliveOwnerIconUrl = relive.owner.asset.large;
    final String reliveCoverPhotoUrl = relive.asset.stream.thumbnail;
    final String reliveDescription = relive.owner.name;

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(reliveCoverPhotoUrl, holder.backgroundImage, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            holder.imageLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            holder.imageLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            holder.imageLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(reliveOwnerIconUrl, holder.profilePicture, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    holder.imageLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    holder.imageLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    holder.imageLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                    holder.imageLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            holder.eyeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.relive);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            holder.imageLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    holder.reliveDescription.setText(reliveDescription);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelivePlayerActivity.StartReliveReviewActivity((ChannelDetailsActivity) holder.itemView.getContext(), relive.asset.stream.url, relive.experienceGuid, relive.guid, holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public final int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

final class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final CircleImageView profilePicture;
    private final ImageView eyeIcon;
    private final ImageView backgroundImage;
    private final TextView reliveDescription;
    private final ProgressBar imageLoading;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        profilePicture = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_circle_image);
        eyeIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_circle_image);
        backgroundImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_image);
        reliveDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_textview);
        imageLoading = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_loading);
    }
}
```

}

This is my layout:

activity_channel_details

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#017789"
    android:textAlignment="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white_trans"
        android:src="@drawable/zeality" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_cover_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frame"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                    <co.zeality.vrplayer.views.HexagonImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_hex"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                </FrameLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_videos"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_relive_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

item_video_recycle_tile

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail_background_video"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_image"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_video_loading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/glasses" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_play_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/play_no_circle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_video_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/img_play_button"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#660c7582"></View>
```

Comment: use one recyclerview with linearlayout manager and its item as another recyclerview with gridlayout manager.

Comment: You need to handle this in your adapter.  You will determine which position you want to have a horizontal RecyclerView, and you will create that view differently for that specific adapter position in there.

in that position you will create your view to be an Recycler

Answer (score 5):

you should use one recyclerView (vertical) as parent and at time of bind view in adapter at position 1 you return one view which is contain recyclerView(horizontal) and load other adapter for that recyclerView. please refer diagram for proper understanding.

```
Main RecyclerView (vertical):   
    ---------------------------
    +   Item 1
    ---------------------------
    +   Second RecyclerView (Horizontal)
    ---------------------------
    +   Item 2
    ---------------------------
```

Parent RecyclerView Adapter code:

```
    @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            if (position == 1)
                return 0;
            else 
                return 1;
        }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if (viewType == 0) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_second_recylerView_layout, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder1(v);
        }
        else{
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder2(v);
        }

    }
```

now you need to implement second Adapter for horizontal recycleView.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried messing with it put it's still too complicated. Do you have maybe some kind of reference or sample?