# Make NEXT button in HorizontalView to scroll through different ImageView

Tags: android, scroll, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-view

I have an HorizontalView. Inside, there is a LinearLayout where I add multiple ImageView through code. I want to implement the NEXT and PREVIOUS button so it scrolls automatically. I also want to hide the buttons when I reach the end of my HorizontalView.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnPkm.jpg

I don't know how to do it.

Edit: This CardView is inside of a recyclerView.

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    >

    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nombrecito"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:fontFamily="fonts/rugs_font.otf"/>

        <RelativeLayout>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="254dp"                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"

                    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

                    <ImageView

                        android:id="@+id/foto"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                        android:contentDescription="fotografía"
                        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>
            <ImageButton
                android:shape="ring"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#ceb06a"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_48dp"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:shape="ring"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#ceb06a"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_48dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:rowCount="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnLike"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:inAnimation="@anim/slide_in_likes_counter"
                android:outAnimation="@anim/slide_out_likes_counter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_heart_outline_grey" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnShare"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:onClick="share"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />

        </GridLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: why not using view pager for this?

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try and see how it work. I'll keep you in touch

Comment: You can try recycler view

Comment: I can try it but I already have a recycler view. Inside are all those cardViews. Will that be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way to implement this case, is to use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), because ViewPager wont show you two pics without listing to certain pic

Make it horizontal with

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true)
```

add recycler and two buttons in RelativeLayout, put buttons over the recycler in correct positins

for example, for left button use

`android:layout_alignParent=true` & `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

To make buttons work use smth like

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. But I already have a recycler view. Inside are all those cardView. Will it be a problem?

Comment: i think that you should make horizontal recyclerview inside a vertical recyclerview, now you have just a horizontal scrollview in recycler view. smth like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41714993/horizontal-recyclerview-inside-vertical-recyclerview[

Comment: I change it and now kinda works. I have this:
holder.btnPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            holder.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(1);
                        }
                    });
For 0 doesn't work. Don't know why

Comment: Nevermind. It works. Just that it wasn't 0, 1, 2. It was 2, 1, 0

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the image and i would recommend using [ViewPager](https://dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using) for this.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try and see how it work. I'll keep you in touch